# Geometry nodes: How to compare two object's faces position and select the faces with equal positon

Tags: geometry, geometry-nodes

I have two Susanne objects

1. A normal looking Susanne and
2. One that at some part has distorted faces (see pic)

How can I compare the position of the faces of the two Susanne's and then select the faces with equal positon. My guess would be to use the `Position` field, `Capture Attributes` and then a `Comparison` node. But I can't really get it done. Maybe a different field? Any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...just an idea.

I would have liked to test this with your blend file, but on the fly, this might be a solution:

Try using the node `Raycast` along the *normals* to see what differences there are. If the length of the vector of the *Hit Position* is equal $0$ (adjust Epsilon?), it should actually work.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks! It worked :D